# mysql: turn around like

Tags: mysql, sql-like

i have a table like this

```
id, title
1, hello world
2, world hello
```

and i like to search for all ids that matches this php expression:

```
$searchstring = "hello world is yours"
if (strstr($searchstring,mysql(title)){echo found}
```

in mysql i often used this:

```
select id from table where title LIKE '%....%'
```

but i need it the other side:

```
select id from table where "hello word is yours" LIKE %title%
```

the result must be id 1 "hello word"

can anybody telle me the correct syntax?

Answer (score 2):

```
select id from table
where 'hello word is yours' LIKE concat('%', replace(title, ' ', '%'), '%')
```

Answer (score 1):

use `CONCAT`

```
select id 
from tableName
where 'hello word is yours' LIKE CONCAT('%',title,'%')
```

Answer (score 1):

As an alternative, you might consider using a [Full Text Search](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/fulltext-boolean.html).  If you create an FTS index, it could be much more efficient and would provide for intuitive search strings:

```
SELECT id FROM tablename WHERE MATCH (title)
      AGAINST ('hello world is yours' IN BOOLEAN MODE);
```